# Multiple GUIs in Matlab using GUIDE

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I want to plot of data generated through push button action on one GUI into another GUI's axes object. Please let me know how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

This [blog post](http://blinkdagger.com/matlab/matlab-gui-how-to-easily-share-data-between-two-separate-guis/) might help steer you in the right direction. You basically need to pass the axes handles from your first gui to your data generation gui, and then update them in the second gui.